# Как посчитать частоту появления триграммы в тексте?

Tags: алгоритм

Добрый день. Правильно ли я понимаю, что для подсчёта частоты появления триграммы в тексте, нужно, во-первых, знать, сколько раз данная триграмма встречалась в тексте, во-вторых, сколько всего различных триграмм в тексте, но я не понял, как именно нужно считать триграммы, как повторяющиеся, так и их общее количество. На картинке представлено два способа, и какой из них правильный?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сколько раз триграмма `xxx` :) встречается в тексте `xxxxxxxx`? по сути, от ответа на этот вопрос зависит, как считать...

Comment: @Harry имею в виду, нужно считать через каждые три символа или брать очередной символ в тексте и от него уже отсчитывать три символа? на картинке я просто ввёл рандомные буквы

Comment: Ну откуда же мне знать, что вам требуется?

Comment: @Harry хорошо, тогда спрошу так, Вы знаете, как в принципе считать триграммы/биграммы в тексте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй способ (с наложением) "более верный". Вот, например, цитата из английской Wiki:

```
"the quick red" has the following character-level trigrams
(where an underscore "_" marks a space):
the
he_
e_q
_qu
qui
uic
ick
ck_
k_r
_re
red
```

Вот выдержка из Postgres доков:

```
При выделении триграмм, содержащихся в строке, считается, что перед каждым
словом находятся два пробела, а после — один пробел. Например, из строки
"cat" выделяется набор триграмм: " c", " ca", "cat" и "at ". Из строки
"foo|bar" выделяются триграммы: " f", " fo", "foo", "oo ", " b", " ba",
 "bar" и "ar ".
```

Правда, иногда используют и первый вариант, если имплементатору кажется, что это проще, и не приводит к существенному искажению частот n-грамм. [Пруф](https://netpeak.net/ru/blog/probability_theory_to_protect_serp/)